# Using multiple RNNs for different feature time intervals

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working with a dataset that consists of time series data of 50 different parameter.
As usual, these time series are quite irregular. However, there are parameter groups that have a pretty similar interval. More precisely, there are about

- 10 parameter that occur together **every minute**.
- 10 parameter that occur together **every 3 hours**.
- 30 parameter  that occur together **every day**.

Now I want to use some kind of RNN, e.g. LSTM, before using a dense layer to implement a classification task. Since the data is irregular, I was thinking of using an aggregation window and a set of statistical features such as min, max, mean, etc. to create data packets that can be passed to the recurrent units. However, suppose we use an aggregation window of 1 day, we obviously lose too much information about the parameters that update every minute. If instead we use an aggregation window of every minute, there are about 1440 bundles in which 30 features remain empty because nothing changes.

The next idea was to use three RNN streams, one for each interval, i.e. minute, 3 hours and every day. However, I am having trouble understanding what my training data would need to look like to train the entire model end-to-end.

Any ideas or links to work that takes a similar approach?

Note that the predicting interval would be something like 15 minutes

Thanks a lot!